# Editing existing React D3 force layout graph to use a circle instead of images supplied

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js, force-layout

I've been trying to get my head around creating d3 graphs with Reactjs, and was looking at an existing [example](https://codepen.io/trey-davis/pen/WOoXyQ?editors=0010) of a Codepen graph. Here the nodes are flags of a country pulled from a url, however I want to replace the flags with simple circles. I created a .css .circle as follows

```
.circle
  stroke: red
  stroke-width: 20px
  fill: red
  background-color: #000
  position: absolute
```

Then I tried replacing the const node in the js file with this to render circles instead but instead nothing replaces the flags.

```
const node = d3.select('.chartContainer')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(data.nodes).enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', d => {return 'circle circle-'  +  d.code;})
        .call(d3.drag()
           .on('start', dragStart)
           .on('drag', drag)
           .on('end', dragEnd)
        ).on('mouseover',d => {
          tooltip.html(d.country)
            .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 5 +'px')
            .style('top', d3.event.pageY + 5 + 'px')
            .style('opacity', .9);
        }).on('mouseout', () => {
          tooltip.style('opacity', 0)
            .style('left', '0px')
            .style('top', '0px');
        });
```

What should I be doing instead?